# Enable Package Control to Sublimetext-2

Tags: sublimetext

My Question is regarding to sublime text2 editor. I need to install Package Controller on it. And i want to enable sublime-terminal. I am very confused. please help me to resolve it.

Thanks,
Shamith c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that Ctrl+' does it sometimes (on Windows, at any rate)

Answer (score 1):

The Sublime Console is triggered with CTRL+`.

The instructions to install Package Control can be found here: http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation.

Answer (score 0):

The comibation ctrl+` never worked for me (Linux AND Windows :-/ ) So I pasted the following into the user specific key bindings:

```
[
   { "keys": ["ctrl+#"], "command": "show_panel", "args": {"panel": "console", "toggle": true} }
]
```

An alternative would be the menu: View >> Show console